# Add context menu item in Outlook?

Tags: delphi, outlook

How can I add an item to the context menu in Outlook from a Delphi application, while the Delphi application is running?

Comment: This is rather hard to achieve from a different process. The traditional way to extend Office applications is through a COM add-in. These are tricky to write. I don't know for 100% certainty that context menus can be extended but I would expect so. The easiest way in Delphi to produce a COM add-in is to use Add-in Express.

Comment: Link for [Add-In Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-delphi/) that David mentioned. You might also find this helpful if you write that add-in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215389/how-to-create-an-outlook-plugin-using-delphi

Comment: seems like a small nightmare which i shall move trough .. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an com add-in for outlook to customize/create your context menu, and from there you can check if your delphi app is up then do the changes that you need.

To customize outlook (com add-in app), you can use a 3 party lib called add-in express, using that lib is very easy customize outlook/word/excel.

http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-delphi/programming-outlook.php